# Convert large data frame into transaction format for arules in R

Tags: r, arules

I have several historical orders information with two columns as a data frame: OrderID and Item. It contains about 1 Million records. I am trying to do association rules mining with this data frame and in order to utilize the arules package, i will have to convert the large data frame into transactions format. However, it takes very long time to convert and i tried with smaller data frames (300K rows) with the same structure, the conversion took several seconds to finish, but for the larger one, it takes for ever. Since i will work on even larger data set for association rules mining, is there any more efficient way to accomplish this?

I am using a fairly powerful machine and succeeded in smaller data frames.
Below is the code i used to do the conversion.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(arules)
OrderID<-c("0001","0001","0002","0002")
Item<-c("ProductA","ProductB","ProductB","ProductC")
df<-data.frame(OrderID,Item)
df$OrderID<-as.factor(df$OrderID)
df$Item<-as.factor(df$Item)

df_trans<-as(split(df[,"Item"],df[,"OrderID"]),"transactions")
```

Comment: after waiting for a long time, i get the error message:  _Error: cannot allocate vector of size 43.3 Gb_

Comment: maybe the write and read as transaction trick could help her? https://www.r-bloggers.com/data-frames-and-transactions/. You might have to create the data to write first which could be done using dplyr: df %>% group_by(OrderID) %>% summarise(transactions = paste0(Item, collapse = ", "))

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue. Here is a solution from the manual page for `?transactions`:

```
   ## example 4: creating transactions from a data.frame with 
   ## transaction IDs and items (by converting it into a list of transactions first) 
     a_df3 <- data.frame(
       TID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3), 
       item=c("a","b","a","b","c", "b")
       )
     a_df3
     trans4 <- as(split(a_df3[,"item"], a_df3[,"TID"]), "transactions")
     trans4
     inspect(trans4)

   ## Note: This is very slow for large datasets. It is much faster to 
   ## read transactions using read.transactions() with format = "single".
   ## This can be done using an anonymous file.
     write.table(a_df3, file = tmp <- file(), row.names = FALSE)
     trans4 <- read.transactions(tmp, format = "single",
       header = TRUE, cols = c("TID", "item"))
     close(tmp)
     inspect(trans4)
```